# Python - k-ary tree list-representation pre- and postorder traversal

Tags: python, tree, traversal

I'm creating a python class for a tree in which each node has n children (but each child only has one node). I need to implement two methods, pre-order and post-order. I'm stuck on pre-order.

This is what I have so far:

```
class KTree:
  def __init__(self, n, lst = []):
    self._tree = lst
    self._n = n

  def children(self, i):
    tree = self._tree
    n = self._n
    result = []
    for k in range(n*i+1, n*i+n+1):
        if k<len(tree):
            result.append(tree[k])
        else:
            pass
    return result

  def child_indices(self, i): 
    #returns list of the indices of the children of i
    tree=self._tree
    n = self._n
    result=[]
    for k in range(n*i+1, n*i+n+1):
        if k<len(tree):
            result.append(k)
    return result

  def parent(self, i):
    tree = self._tree
    n = self._n
    result = (i-1)//n
    return tree[result]

  def pre_order(self):
    result=[]
    stack = []
    stack.append(0)
    k=0
    while k<len(stack):
        result.append(self._tree[stack[k]])
        for index in self.child_indices(k):
            stack.append(index)
        k+=1
    return result
```

For the tree `[20, 2, 123, 1, 5, 4, 438]` (diagram shown below, I think the output of preorder should be `[20, 2, 1, 5, 123, 4, 438]`. My current code is outputting `[20, 2, 123, 1, 5, 40, 438]`.

```
     20
   /    \
  2     123
 / \    / \
1   5  4  438
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use recursion. To make that possible you could define a parameter for your function: the index from where to start generating the pre order list.

Then the code looks like this:

```
def pre_order(self, k = 0):
    result = [self._tree[k]]
    for index in self.child_indices(k):
        result.extend(self.pre_order(index))
    return result
```

The post order variant of this looks quite similar, but you add the given node only *after* having added the children's post order lists:

```
def post_order(self, k = 0):
    result = []
    for index in self.child_indices(k):
        result.extend(self.post_order(index))
    return result + [self._tree[k]]
```

Comment: Thank you- I couldn't figure out how to implement recursion because I didn't think of adding k as a parameter. Genius!

Answer (score 0):

The pre order is implemented recursively as

Check if the current node is empty / null. 
Display the data part of the root (or current node). 
Traverse the left subtree by recursively calling the pre-order function. 
Traverse the right subtree by recursively calling the pre-order function.

This is from wikepedia.